# Google Cloud Compute Duplicate VM affects the original

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I have a website comugg.com thats using google compute engine. I created a duplicate of the VM instance on google compute engine and then proceeded to change the url on the mysql database for wordpress wp_options. i also created a nameserver on google cloud compute and updated the nameservers on the duplicate website, carcomputersource.com. However carcomputersource.com redirects to comugg.com and any changes i make to the carcomputersource.com changes comugg.com

what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit the wp-config.php file and change the values:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Here you can find more information: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL